# Why TypeError for onclick function? - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am developing an app to fetch posts from a API and load posts.Everything is working fine except `gotopost` function.After rendering this error comes **`TypeError: Cannot read property 'gotopost' of undefined`**

But don't know why this is happening.Though i bind that function and declared that function above the render() function

below is the code

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';

import './App.css';

class Todos extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      posts: [],
      singleLoaded: false,
      singlepost: []
    }
    this.fetchposts = this.fetchposts.bind(this);

  }
  fetchposts(){
    fetch("http://smashingdevs.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/")
      .then((response) => {
          return response.json();
      })
      .then((posts) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            posts: posts
          });
      });

  }

  render() {
    let container;
    if(this.state.isLoaded){
      container = <Allposts posts={this.state.posts}/>;
    }else if(this.state.singleLoaded){
      container = <Singleposts />;
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Hello  there</h2>
        <button onClick={this.fetchposts}>
          fetch posts
        </button>
        {container}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Allposts extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
  gotopost(){}
  render(){
    return (<div className="row mt-5">
      {
        this.props.posts.map(function(post){
            return <div className="col-md-6 mb-2" key={post.id}>
                <div className="card" >
 // Problem is here on onClick
                    <a href={post.link} onClick={this.gotopost.bind(this)} className="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
              </div>
          })
      }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
class Singleposts extends React.Component{

}
export default Todos;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` will not be what you expect inside the function given to `map`. You can `bind` the function to `this`, or you can use an arrow function to use the surrounding lexical scope, and `this` will be what you want.

```
class Allposts extends React.Component {
  gotopost() {}

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row mt-5">
        {this.props.posts.map(post => {
          return (
            <div className="col-md-6 mb-2" key={post.id}>
              <div className="card">
                <a
                  href={post.link}
                  onClick={this.gotopost.bind(this)}
                  className="btn btn-primary"
                >
                  Go somewhere
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use arrow function:

```
  this.props.posts.map((post) => {
```

Answer (score 0):

This is common error of JS. When you go to internal function, var `this` in this scope is no longer outside class anymore. The workaround is assigning `this` to another variable at the top of method.

```html
render(){
  const self = this;

    return (<div className="row mt-5">
      {
        this.props.posts.map(function(post){
            return <div className="col-md-6 mb-2" key={post.id}>
                <div className="card" >
 // use self instead this
                    <a href={post.link} onClick={self.gotopost.bind(this)} className="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
              </div>
          })
      }
      </div>
    )
  }
```